# Yii relation with multiple rows

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 tables i'm trying to join using relation

my tables are

```
State                            Store              Contacts
CA|California                1|BESTBUY|CA          1|1|Phone|888888
                                                   2|1|Phone|555555
                                                   3|1|Phone|777777
```

In my Store model, i have this is my relations

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            '_state' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'state'),
            '_contact' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Contact', '', 'foreignKey' => array('id'=>'store_id')),
        );
    }
```

how do i get ALL the phone number for id `1`? or is there a better way?

when i call `$model->_contact->Phone;` i get this error

```
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations seem fine, but $model->_contact provides you with an array of contact models. To show all phone numbers you could do:

```
foreach($model->_contact as $contact) {
   echo $contact->Phone;
}
```

Comment: does my relations go into my store model or my contacts model? cos i get error `Property "Store.store_id" is not defined.` the `store_id` is in the `Contact` table

Comment: solved it using `'_contact' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Contact', 'store_id'),` thanks